# Display R Dataframe in PHP

Tags: php, r, dataframe

I'm trying to display the contents of an R dataframe in php after calling an R script. This is what i've done so far:

```
<?php
exec("Rscript /home/pi/Desktop/project/function.R", $result);
print_r(array_values($result));
?>
```

I can confirm that the R script successfully executes, but i'm having trouble displaying the returned dataframe on the webpage. I haven't been able to find a good example anywhere online to follow. Thanks!

Comment: Check permissions, and whats it supposed to be returning? As you not showing your r code.

Comment: it's supposed to be returning a R Dataframe (has 5 columns). As of now , all it shows on the webpage is  "Array()". For permissions, you mean just set the php script and r script to executable right?

Comment: Please show the ending of R script. Does it print dataframe to console or just assigns it to a variable?

Comment: the R script is 500 lines long so I wasn't going to post it. it does print the entire dataframe to the console when i use "return(result)"  
last few lines in console:
113 2018-03-15 22:20:00 2018-03-15 23:20:00 44889.80
114 2018-03-15 22:25:00 2018-03-15 23:25:00 44821.23
115 2018-03-15 22:30:00 2018-03-15 23:30:00 44757.26
116 2018-03-15 22:35:00 2018-03-15 23:35:00 44697.43
117 2018-03-15 22:40:00 2018-03-15 23:40:00 44641.14
118 2018-03-15 22:45:00 2018-03-15 23:45:00 44577.60
119 2018-03-15 22:50:00 2018-03-15 23:50:00 44519.01
120 2018-03-15 22:55:00 2018-03-15 23:55:00 44465.08